# My game is flickering due to my painting directly in JFrame. How do I use JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've made a snake game as an assignment for college, and it works just fine - except it flickers like crazy. I know it's because I've painted directly in JFrame as opposed to in a JPanel that offers double buffering, but as I don't have much experience with swing I'm not sure how to actually do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class SnakeGame extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener{

//Initiate all the variables we need
public ArrayList<SnakeElement> snakeBody = new ArrayList<SnakeElement>();
public SnakeElement snake = new SnakeElement(100, 100);
public AppleElement apple = new AppleElement();
public int moveSnakeX = 1;
public int moveSnakeY = 0;
public int score = 0;
public int highscore = 0;
public int timer = 0;
public static final Font scoreFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);

//Create the JFrame
public SnakeGame(){
    this.setTitle("Snake");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600,600);
    this.setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    snakeBody.add(snake);
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    t.start();
}

public void drawSomething(){
    timer += 5;
    //Spawns a new apple every 5 seconds
    if(timer >= 5000){
        System.out.println("Apple escaped!");
        Random pos = new Random();
        apple.setX(pos.nextInt(581 + 1 - 21) + 21); //Bound: (20, 580)
        apple.setY(pos.nextInt(581 + 1 - 21) + 21); //Bound: (20, 580)
        timer = 0;
    }

    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    g.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(scoreFont);
    g.drawString("Score: " + score, 500, 60);
    this.checkCollision();
    this.MoveSnake();

    //Draws every element in snakeBody
    for(int i = 0; i < this.snake.getSize()-1; i++) {
        snakeBody.get(i).drawSnake(g);
    }

    //Updates the ArrayList snakeBody: all element-coordinates equals the element-coordinates before them
    for(int i = snakeBody.size()-1; i > 0; i--) {
        SnakeElement penultimate = snakeBody.get(i-1); //Gets the penultimate element in snakeBody
        SnakeElement last = snakeBody.get(i); //Gets the last element in snakeBody
        last.x = penultimate.x; //Sets the x-coordinate for the last element = the x-coordinate for the penultimate element
        last.y = penultimate.y; //Sets the y-coordinate for the last element = the y-coordinate for the penultimate element
    }

    this.snake.drawSnake(g);
    this.apple.drawApple(g);
}

public void MoveSnake(){
    this.snake.setX(this.snake.getX() + moveSnakeX); //If moveSnakeX = 1 or -1, the snake moves horizontally
    this.snake.setY(this.snake.getY() + moveSnakeY); //If moveSnakeY = 1 or -1, the snake moves vertically

    //If snake crashes into a wall, save score and show "Game over"-message
    if(this.snake.getX() == 0 || this.snake.getX() == 600 || this.snake.getY() == 0 || this.snake.getY() == 600){
        if(score > highscore){
            highscore = score;
        }
        this.GameOver();
    }
}

public void checkCollision(){
    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(snake.getX(), snake.getY(), snake.getHeight(), snake.getWidth());
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(apple.getX(), apple.getY(), apple.getHeight(), apple.getWidth());
    Random pos = new Random();

    //If snake eats the apple, spawn a new apple and grow snake, reset the timer and add 5 points to your score
    if(r1.intersects(r2)){
        System.out.println("Snake got the apple!");
        apple.setX(pos.nextInt(581 + 1 - 21) + 21); //Random x-coordinate within (20, 580)
        apple.setY(pos.nextInt(581 + 1 - 21) + 21); //Random y-coordinate within (20, 580)

        this.snake.setSize(this.snake.getSize() +15);
        this.GrowSnake();
        timer = 0;
        score += 5;
    }
}

//Adds a snake element at the end of the snake
public void GrowSnake(){
    for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
        SnakeElement snakeButt = new SnakeElement(snakeBody.get(snakeBody.size() - 1).x, snakeBody.get(snakeBody.size() - 1).y);
        this.snakeBody.add(snakeBody.size(), snakeButt);
    }
}

//Show an option message when game is over
Object [] options = {"Start over", "Exit game"};
public void GameOver(){
    int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "Snake died!" +
                    "\nScore: " + score +
                    "\nHighscore: " + highscore,
            "Game over!",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[0]);

    //Reset variables if player wants to restart game
    if(answer == 0){
        this.snake.setX(100);
        this.snake.setY(100);
        this.snake.setSize(0);
        moveSnakeX = 1;
        moveSnakeY = 0;
        this.drawSomething();
        score = 0;
    } else { //Exit game
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    this.drawSomething();

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        //If snake is NOT moving down, make snake move up. If snake is moving down, it's not allowed to move up
        if(moveSnakeY != 1){
            System.out.println("Up");
            moveSnakeX = 0;
            moveSnakeY = -1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot turn in the opposite direction!");
        }
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        if(moveSnakeY != -1){
            System.out.println("Down");
            moveSnakeX = 0;
            moveSnakeY = 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot turn in the opposite direction!");
        }
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        if(moveSnakeX != 1){
            System.out.println("Left");
            moveSnakeX = -1;
            moveSnakeY = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot turn in the opposite direction!");
        }
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        if(moveSnakeX != -1){
            System.out.println("Right");
            moveSnakeX = 1;
            moveSnakeY = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot turn in the opposite direction!");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.drawSomething();
}
```

Comment: Also please check out the [many other similar questions that can be found on this subject](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+how+to+animate+in+jpanel&*). In the future, you'll likely get much more specific answers if you first attempt to solve the issue yourself, and then show your attempt here -- i.e., try to do an animation inside your own JPanel's paintComponent method and show us that attempt, also telling us what problems you may be having with it. Good luck!

Comment: Also, don't call `getGraphics()` on a component to get a Graphics object since the object thus obtained will not persist. To prove that this is true, minimize and then restore a rendered GUI, and you'll see your drawing disappear. Instead do your drawing in the `paintComponent` override of a JPanel or JComponent. Also, you'll want to change your Timer's delay to something that is more realistic, such as 12 to 15, and base your physics on real measured time slices.